# CocoaPods folder does not exist / permissions error

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I'm new to CocoaPods, I tried running `'pod install'` on my Mac to install my pod, but I'm getting a permissions error with the folder `/Users/username/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`. That folder doesn't even exist! Did I accidentally delete it at one point? How do I restore it?
There is however a folder called `/Library/Caches` but its not under my username, its at the root.

I'm a little confused. If someone can just direct me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the full error message:

```
Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/nachshonfertel/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a permissions error. And the folder I thought didn't exist, was hidden in finder > Go > (Hold Down Option Key) Library

Took me 2 full days to finally figure it out!

Comment: in my case folder is present in Library, still error

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Add CocoaPods folder on ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods then try

> pod install

OR

2. Give full permission on you project

> 1. cd your-project
> 2. chmod -R 777 .
> 3. cd ios
> 4. pod install

Comment: how to reach on this path ?

Comment: that's no problem.just try it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this issue for a while. For some reason, in my case the problem was that the folder ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods was not there, and cocoapods wasn't able to create it when running 'pod install'. Hence the permission error.

After trying several things, I created that folder manually (which prompted for my password), ran 'pod update' and my problem was fixed!

Hope this saves someone some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem creating the missing folder Users (in my case the error was Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/Users) and give full permission to all users.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct permissions for the folder: as in the picture. (Sorry for the localization)

[image: right permissions]

Answer (score -1):

Are you using system Ruby or have you installed Ruby with `sudo`?

You basically have 2 options:

- use `sudo pod install`

  - Probably the easiest/fastest way for you go forward
  - This typically causes more problems than Ruby being owned by non-root
  - When you install packages they will have sudo access!
- Install Ruby, non-sudo; you can try

  - [github.com/postmodern/ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) together with [github.com/postmodern/chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) (my personal favourite), [rvm.io](https://rvm.io/) is also very popular
  - The benefit of this approach is that you also can switch Ruby version whenever you like (and as mentioned above; <strike>more secure</strike> less insecure..)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to **solve my issue** in following *steps*:

1. Create CocoaPods folder (if it doesn't exist) `cd ~/Library/Caches  && mkdir CocoaPods`
2. Give access to CocoaPods folder `sudo chmod 777 Cocoapods`
3. Create Pods folder `cd CocoaPods && mkdir Pods`
4. Give access to Pods folder `sudo chmod 777 Pods`

I hope it helps !