# React native problem in installing pod after eject from Expo

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, expo

after I eject my project using `expo eject`. then I install dependencies using `yarn install` and then it said that I need to install `pod` then I `cd` into `ios` folder and run `pod install` and receive this:

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-125 ios % pod install
Installing unimodules:
 expo-application@2.4.1 from ../node_modules/expo-application/ios
 expo-av@8.7.0 from ../node_modules/expo-av/ios
 expo-constants@9.3.5 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-error-recovery@1.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
 expo-file-system@9.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-font@8.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-image-loader@1.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
 expo-image-picker@9.2.1 from ../node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios
 expo-keep-awake@8.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
 expo-linear-gradient@8.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios
 expo-location@10.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-location/ios
 expo-permissions@10.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
 expo-secure-store@9.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-secure-store/ios
 expo-splash-screen@0.8.1 from ../node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
 expo-sqlite@8.5.0 from ../node_modules/expo-sqlite/ios
 expo-updates@0.4.2 from ../node_modules/expo-updates/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@1.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios
 unimodules-core@6.0.0 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios
 unimodules-font-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.7.0 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.4.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `assemblybuildingproject`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNDateTimePicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, react-native-date-picker, react-native-maps, and react-native-safe-area-context

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command


/usr/local/bin/pod install

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack


   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
       Xcode : 12.5 (12E262)
         Git : git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
 

### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0


### Podfile

ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'assemblybuildingproject' do
  use_unimodules!
# @generated begin react-native-maps - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-2f0a6817224f18601deb2879c9e783ba07387bc9
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
# @generated end react-native-maps
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Uncomment the code below to enable Flipper.
  #
  # You should not install Flipper in CI environments when creating release
  # builds, this will lead to significantly slower build times.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work.
  #
  #  use_flipper!
  #  post_install do |installer|
  #    flipper_post_install(installer)
  #  end
end


### Error

Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/ec2-user/Desktop/emiremad-assembly-react-native-8ec5397870f3/ios/Pods
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `mkdir_p'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb:66:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:198:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:198:in `sandbox'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in `installer_for_config'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:47:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'


――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Permission+denied+%40+dir_s_mkdir+-+%2FUsers%2Fec2-user%2FDesktop%2Femiremad-assembly-react-native-8ec5397870f3%2Fios%2FPods&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
```

Comment: Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/ec2-user/Desktop/emiremad-assembly-react-native-8ec5397870f3/ios/Pods

-- your system permissions need to be fixed. related stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181915/cocoapods-folder-does-not-exist-permissions-error